# Speed up compile time with make

Tags: makefile

Is there anyway to speed up the time it takes a run a `make` compile. We have a package that takes 12 minutes and looking to speed that up. Any flags to pass to make, or way to run it parallel.

Answer (score 7):

Try running `make -jN` with N being the number of cores in your system if you haven't already.

Try using fewer compile time optimizations if it applies (avoid `-O3` in particular).

You can also take a look at [distcc](http://code.google.com/p/distcc/).

Comment: Make -j is definitely what you want, here. The suggestion provided - "look at distcc" - is also a very good one.